# Serving Univeral Sentence Encoder Model using tensorflow serving and docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have universal sentence encoder model saved on my local drive. I am trying to serve the model on docker container using tensorflow serving.

Command:

```
sudo docker run -p 8502:8502 --name tf-serve -v /home/ubuntu/first/models:/models -t tensorflow/serving --model_base_path=/models/test
```

where `/home/ubuntu/first/models` is the folder path to my model files.

After running initially it is going into an infinite loop.

What is happening here?! Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

edit your command like this:

```
sudo docker run -p 8502:8502 --name tf-serve -v /home/ubuntu/first/models:/models/test -t tensorflow/serving --model_base_path=/models/test
```

your `--model_base_path` is `/models/test` so you need to copy the files into that folder in your `-v`

Comment: I have model files in a folder named "1" inside the test folder only. The folder structure is like this /first/models/test/1

inside 1 I have a "variable" directory & "saved_model.pb" file

Comment: then try `-v /home/ubuntu/first/models/test/1:/models/test'